# In TYPO3 Fluid, how do I access a variable from inside a foreach loop?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.1.x, fedext

I am building a navigation with the [VHS Menu ViewHelper](https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/MenuViewHelper.html). Below is the entire code. 
My question is probably very basic fluid though.

Inside a scope, how do I access a variable that exists outside that scope - or how do I pass it into that scope?

EDIT: I've updated my code to not use dashes in variable names as well as assigned different names to v:page.menu with as="menuLevel0".

---

The full code:

```
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
<ul id="nav" class="grid-full classic">
    <v:page.menu as="menuLevel0" expandAll="1" useShortcutData="1" levels="4" classHasSubpages="parent" classFirst="first" classLast="last">
        <f:for each="{menuLevel0}" as="itemLevel0" iteration="iterLevel0">
            <li class="{itemLevel0.class} level0 nav-{iterLevel0.cycle} level-top">
                <a href='{itemLevel0.link}' class='level-top'><span>
                    <f:if condition="{itemLevel0.nav_title}"><f:then>{itemLevel0.nav_title}</f:then><f:else>{itemLevel0.title}</f:else></f:if>
                nav-{iterLevel0.cycle}</span>
                </a>
                <f:if condition="{itemLevel0.hasSubPages}">
                    <f:then>
                        <v:page.menu as="menuLevel1" expandAll="1" classHasSubpages="parent" classFirst="first" classLast="last">
                            <ul class="level0">
                                <f:for each="{menuLevel1}" as="itemLevel1" iteration="iterLevel1">
                                    <li class="{itemLevel1.class} level1 nav-{iterLevel0.cycle}-{iterLevel1.cycle}">
                                        <a href='{itemLevel1.link}' class='level-top'><span>
                                            <f:if condition="{itemLevel1.nav_title}"><f:then>{itemLevel1.nav_title}</f:then><f:else>{itemLevel1.title}</f:else></f:if>
                                            nav-{menuLevel0.iterLevel0.cycle}-{iterLevel1.cycle}
                                        </span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </f:for>
                            </ul>
                        </v:page.menu>
                    </f:then>
                </f:if>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </v:page.menu>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just noticed it's only not working for the first item of the main section.

Comment: and it works with page.menu.directory, see https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/479

Comment: You seem to have a misconception about how to access variables from parent scope. You dont actually need to use ``{menuLevel0.iterLevel0.cycle}``. ``{iterLevel0.cycle}`` is enough.

Comment: That's what I've been doing all the way ... Now, the only difference is that I set `<v:page.menu as="menuLevel0"`. Now `<f:debug>{iterLevel0.cycle}</f:debug>`still returns NULL instead of 1 for the first item (in the parent level, when accessing it from the child level): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11320047/iter.png . I've started thinking it might be a bug, either in `f:for`or in `v:page.menu`.

Answer (score 2):

In fluid, variables are and should be scoped to the blocks you are using.

While you are using our `v:page.menu` ViewHelpers, you need to understand the scoping a bit further:

1. Use different names for variables in nested scopes: `{levelOneIterator}` and `{levelTwoIterator}` are good examples for such behaviour
2. As a rule of thumb: Use lowerCamelCased variable names. It prevents fluid from parsing your var-names wrong.

**The reason why your code is not working:**

You assign a `{iter}` variable. Therefore fluid doesn't parse the dash-ified variable name as it detects the undashified identifier first. Dashes have special meaning in fluid and you can run into kind-of race conditions there.

To take this a bit further:

```
    
    {foo-bar} // echos "baz"
    
    {foo-bar} // echos "bing", as the bar vaiable is read first, and "foo-" isnt a variable in the current scope

```

**Update:**

Accessing variables from a parent scope doesnt require prefixing your var-call. In a child for-loop, you can access the parent iteration by simply calling the var.

`<f:for each="{iterable}" as="iterableItem iteration="iteratorRoot">
       {iteratorRoot.index} <!-- Echoes the current, zero-indexed iteration -->
       <f:for each="{iterableItem}" as="subItem" iteration="iterationChild">
          <!-- STILL echoes the current, zero-indexed iteration -->
         {iteratorRoot.index}
          <!-- Echoes the current, zero-indexed sub iteration -->
         {iterationChild.index}
       </f:for>
    </f:for>`

As long as you give different names to the iterators, you can access them in any scope by their originating name. Same goes for the aliased (as="name") named variables.

Comment: Thanks again, Cedric. I've updated my question above. I'm getting there. But still I don't see how I can access the parent scope (or something like a global variable) or pass in the desired variable from the parent scope into the child scope to use there. That must be possible, isn't it?

Comment: I've also tried `<v:var.set name="menuLevel0iter" value="{iterLevel0.cycle}"></v:var.set>`and in the child scope `{menuLevel0iter}`- but of course the scope isnt global either

Answer (score 1):

Try not using "-" in the variable-name! Use CamelCase instead:

```
<f:render section="layer2" arguments="{uid: curPage.uid, parentIter: iter.cycle}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
public function listAction() {
    $events = $this->eventsRepository->getEventsList();
    $this->view->assign('eventsList', $events);
}
```

In View File you can access like this.

```
<f:for each="{eventsList}" as="events">
    <tr>
        <td> {events.event_id} </td>        
        <td> <f:link.external uri="{events.event_link}" target="_blank">{events.event_link}</f:link.external></td>
        <td><f:format.date format="d-m-Y">{events.event_date}</f:format.date></td>
    </tr>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not to use the same varibale name for the iterators in both of your foreach loops?

Comment: I've tried it now, seems to make no difference. Actually, in the second section, the variable that's passed in, has a different name already (parent-iter vs. iter)